# Rename tag [parselivequery] to [parse-live-query]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The tag [parselivequery] should be renamed to [parse-live-query] to align with the rest of the Parse Platform related tags.

This tag request is part of the Parse Community's effort to maintain Parse Platform related tags on Stack Exchange, as described [here](https://community.parseplatform.org/t/parse-related-stackexchange-tags).